# Bootstrap Table column header not aligned

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

[image]

```
                    <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="d-flex">
                            <th class="col-0">JOB ID</th>
                            <th class="col-0">JOB STATUS</th>
                            <th class="col-0">USER</th>
                            
                            <th class="col-0">BG TASK STATUS</th>
                            <th class="col-2">BG TASK RESULT</th>
                            <th class="col-0">BG TASK CREATED TIME</th>
                            <th class="col-0">BG TASK COMPLETED TIME</th>
                            
                            <th class="col-0">DETAIL LOG LINK</th>    
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        
                        
                        <tr class="d-flex">
                            <td class="col-0">15</td>
                            <td class="col-0">success</td>
                            <td class="col-0">None</td>
                           
                           
                            <td class="col-0"></td>
                            <td class="col-2"></td>
                            <td class="col-0"></td>
                            <td class="col-0"></td>
                            
                            
                           <td class="col-0"><a href="/logs?job_id=15">Job Details</a></td>
                            
                        </tr>
                        
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete the className="d-flex" in tr tag

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the class `text-justify` to the table so that the text will be aligned to center